# Structured Data (schema.org) - openingHours for EducationalOrganization

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, structured-data, google-ranking

I'm just about to expand my templates with [schema.org](http://schema.org) attributes and have the following question. With which property can I specify the opening hours for the type [EducationalOrganization](http://schema.org/EducationalOrganization)? Unfortunately, the [openingHours](http://schema.org/openingHours) property is not available here. In addition, there is no type similar to the **EducationalOrganization** type.

Here is the current state of my code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EducationalOrganization" class="ce_text address block">
    <div class="text_container">
        <p>
            <span>
                <strong itemprop="name"><?php echo $this->field('company')->value(); ?></strong><br>
            </span>
        <p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemprop="address">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">
                <?php echo $this->field('street')->value(); ?><br>
            </span>
            <span itemprop="postalCode">
                <?php echo $this->field('zipcode')->value(); ?>
            </span>
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">
                <?php echo $this->field('place')->value(); ?>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            Aus dem Ausland: <span itemprop="telephone"><?php echo $this->field('phone_foreign')->value(); ?></span><br>
            Fax: <span itemprop="telephone"><?php echo $this->field('fax')->value(); ?></span>
        </p>
        <p itemscope itemtype="??????"> <!-- What type can I use here? -->
            <strong>Öffnungszeiten:</strong><br>
            Montag bis Donnerstag: <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Th 08:00-18:00"><?php echo $this->field('mothu')->value(); ?><br>
            Freitag: <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Fr 08:00-15:00"><?php echo $this->field('fri')->value(); ?>
        </p> <!-- Öffnungszeiten Ende -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What type can I use in this case to use the **itemprop="openingHours"** property or is there another workarount, if this is not possible?

---

**UPDATE:**

I have chosen this solution in the meantime. It is read out cleanly by Google and makes more sense in the case of our company.

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
        <strong>Öffnungszeiten:</strong><br>
        Montag bis Donnerstag: <?php echo $this->field('mothu')->value(); ?><br>
        Freitag: <?php echo $this->field('fri')->value(); ?>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Monday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Tuesday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Wednesday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Thursday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Friday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="15:00:00"></time>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are the opening hours for, exactly? For visiting an office? Or for telephone calls?

Comment: @unor The opening hours refer to the telephone service as well as the office hours, in which the participants have the opportunity to come by in person.

Comment: @Codehan25 Note that the property EducationalOrganization is applied to organization. But property http://schema.org/Service is used for a service provided by an organization. These are different ways to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apply the element **[contactPoint](http://schema.org/contactPoint)** with the extension for the
  property **[ContactPoint](http://schema.org/ContactPoint)**.
- Next, select and apply  the element **[hoursAvailable](http://schema.org/hoursAvailable)** with the
  extension for the property **[OpeningHoursSpecification](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification)**.

Create something similar:

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EducationalOrganization">
<h1 itemprop="name">Name of Organization</h1>
<section itemprop=contactPoint itemscope itemtype=http://schema.org/ContactPoint>  
  <h2>Opening hours</h2>
     <meta itemprop="hoursAvailable" content="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 09:00-14:00">
    <p>Normally open daily <time datetime="09:00">9am</time>-<time datetime="14:00">2pm</time></p>
</section>
</main>
```

Check the structured data on **[this Google tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)** and set the required data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It works very well as well. But in the meantime I have decided on a different solution. I've updated my post above and added my solution.

Comment: @Codehan25: Instead of adding a solution to the question post, please edit it out and create an answer for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try CivicStructure or GovernmentOffice.
For Educational Organisations such as school, university there is no need to scope the opening hours. Maybe your organisation is not Educational and you can use another scope for your organisation.

Comment: Our company is a distance learning institute offering various distance learning programs in the sports industry (personal trainer, fitness trainer, etc.). That's why I chose the type of "EducationalOrganization". In your opinion, would another type fit better?

Comment: As you make any profit from this activity, I think best for you fits itemtype LocalBusiness

Comment: @Codehan25 If your training is courses, then you can apply the element http://schema.org/hasCourseInstance with the property http://schema.org/CourseInstance or http://schema.org/Course

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**

I have chosen this solution in the meantime. It is read out cleanly by Google and makes more sense in the case of our company.

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
        <strong>Öffnungszeiten:</strong><br>
        Montag bis Donnerstag: <?php echo $this->field('mothu')->value(); ?><br>
        Freitag: <?php echo $this->field('fri')->value(); ?>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Monday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Tuesday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Wednesday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Thursday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="18:00:00"></time>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/Friday" />
            <time itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00"></time>
            <time itemprop="closes" content="15:00:00"></time>
        </div>
    </div>
```